# Losing contents of a SQL User Defined Table Type/Table-ValueType in SP

Tags: c#, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I'm calling an sp(Sp1) from .Net, passing a data table (as SqlDbType.Structured).  Sp1 has a parameter defined as a udtt, "CREATE TYPE udttInteger AS Table (Id INT)".  Sp1 then dynamically calls Sp2 passing the same udtt parameter.

.Net(Data Table)--> sp1(udtt) -- sp2(udtt)

The problem I'm facing is I appear to lose the content of the uddt in sp2 because my IF statements are effectively being ignored and when I do a count(*) the value is 0.

Is there a limit to how deep you can go with udtt's?

Comment: Not really sure I understand your question here. There is no limit on passing parameters of any type, including table valued parameters. My guess is there is a bug in your code.

Comment: Perhaps if you share your code we can help you find the issue. As it sits right now this is unanswerable.